Why does a Fenestron tail rotor require so much speed compared to an open rotor?
As explained in this video(@3:22) by PilotYellow, a Fenestron tail rotor spins 10x faster than the main rotor while a traditional tail rotor only spins 6x faster.
Why there is so much difference? Aren't ducts supposed to create more thrust? Also, aren't more blades supposed to created more thrust?
What's the reason for the difference?

The speed of a rotating wing, no matter if it is used in a propeller or in a rotor, is normally limited by the onset of transonic speed on its tip, speed which is linearly proportional to its radius/diameter.
I think the H145 is a good example to answer your question: When it was still named BK117, it had a conventional tail rotor with a diameter of 1.9m. The newest version has a fenestron instead, with a diameter of 1.1m. Their ratio is 0.6 which is exactly the number given in your video.

BK117 with conventional tail rotor (source)

BK117-D3 aka H145 with fenestron (source)

Propellers and rotors create thrust by accelerating the air that passes through them. A smaller rotor blows a small amount of air at high speed, a large one blows a large amount of air at low speed, but the force (or momentum change) is the same. So when you make a tail rotor smaller, you have to spin it faster to get the same thrust.
Ducts can improve efficiency, but they're often over rated. They reduce tip loses, but tip loses are small on long, thin blades because the tip is a small part of the overall blade. As the blade gets shorter and more highly loaded, tip loses increase and it becomes worth adding a duct.
Tip loses mean that an area near the tip of a blade isn't making much lift. So you can think of a duct as extending a blade's span by (very roughly) one chord-width. It's not nearly enough to make up for the blade being only 60% of the original length.

I think you are looking at this backwards. The goal going in is to lower the weight of any given tail rotor assembly and it's drive system, both for direct weight savings and because the moving parts are relatively expense on a per-pound basis. The easiest way to do that is to make the rotor smaller. Spinning it faster saves weight on the drive components at equal power delivery. So the goal is to design a rotor that is as small and fast as possible that still makes the target thrust at the target power. As stated in Robin's answer, ducts can considerably increase the effective diameter of a prop (when viewed at equal efficiency). Ducted props move nearly same amount of air as a larger unducted prop, but with very different span loading, a higher advance, and, because they can push the rpms up, run lower torque through the drive.

The fenestron is quite a bit heavier and less efficient than a conventional tail rotor and was added to the ex-MBB, now Eurocopter helicopters after the French side insisted on it.

Everything about the description of the handling issues suggests it is more efficient during normal operations. It has less to give during extreme control demands - that's a typical side effect of improvements to static efficiency. It's why modern small trucks need so many gears when the old ones had three of four - the new engines are more efficient and lighter, but don't have any reserves or torque droop to provide adequate drivability over wide gear ranges. Now we can either say they suck, or we can match them to an appropriate transmission.

@PeterKämpf Okay, I think I understand your point wrt my post's second sentence. I'm going to tweak the wording a bit there.
